# Performance of kd-tree vs brute-force nearest neighbor search on GPU?

Tags: gpu, nearest-neighbors

I wonder if there is any study that compares the performance of kd-tree vs brute-force nearest neighbor search on GPU. [Post #4 on this page](https://forums.khronos.org/showthread.php/7402-kd-tree-nearest-neighbour) suggests that kd-tree may not be the optimal algorithm for GPU but I wonder if there is any data supporting this claim?

Comment: Not GPU, but [scikit-learn KNeighborsClassifier brute](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier.html) is very fast on MNIST 784d, runtimes [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/7054). (Kd-trees are useless above ~ 20d.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ultimately, naive brute-force KNN is an $O(n^2)$ algorithm, while kd-tree is $O(n \log n)$, so at least in theory, kd-tree will eventually win out for a large enough $n$. In practice, the leading constants for a GPU implementation may be vastly different --- we may be comparing $0.0001n^2$ vs $1000n\log n$ --- so it may indeed be the case that the former wins out for *practical problem sizes*.

Now, the reason for the difference in leading constants come down to parallelizability and memory access patterns. Naive KNN is *embarrassingly* parallelizable, and can be implemented entirely using vectorized sequential memory access. By contrast, kd-tree is naturally serial, and requires extensive conditional statements and random memory access. Algorithms like the former enjoy a massive speed-up on a GPU, while those like the latter often run slower on a GPU than a CPU.

Answer (score 2):

Additionally to what @richard-zang said, instead of a "naive brute-force" search, you can often use some refinement, e.g. a [locality-based hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality-sensitive_hashing) or if you have fixed neighbor distance radius, a common approach is to pre-grid/sort the search space to limit the lookup to neighboring cells (commonly used in molecular simulation and referred to as [linked cell list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cell_lists).

Answer (score 0):

- $k$: number of dimensions.
- $n$: number of points.

The naive KNN with brute-force linear scan is $O(kn)$ for both worst-case and average case. When ran on GPU, the speedup can be (roughly) one thousand ($10^3$).

kd-tree's worst case is $O(n)$ for a completely unbalanced tree and $O(n^{1−1/k})$  for the average case. It can be barely parallelized and does not support online/incremental updates well (although amortized time is good enough).

Let's take the average case of kd-tree with a single thread. When $n=2^{20}$ (about 1 million) and $k=100$, (this is a good average case for text-based classification problem) then kd-tree needs about 1 million operations in the average case, where linear scan needs 100 million operations. Considering the GPU speedup, then linear is 10 times faster than kd-tree.

We can see that only when $k$ is very small that kd-tree can beat linear scan, but that is pretty rare in real-world problems. This problem is called the dimension curse which led to the research of Approximate Nearest Neighbor (ANN) search algorithms for practical implementations: e.g. https://arxiv.org/pdf/1702.05911.pdf.